# Asp.net core proxy keeps throwing 403 (asp.net core 3.1 + a bit of server-side blazor)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, proxy, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm using AspNetCore.Proxy to proxy the call to a static resource to an external service. I do some preprocessing to verify the user and to construct the URL to the external service (which I want to keep hidden from the user).

In my Startup.Configure() I have this:

```
app.UseProxies(builder =>
            {
                builder.Map("attached_resource/{id}", proxy =>
                {
                    proxy.UseHttp((context, arguments) =>
                    {
                        var scope = context.RequestServices
                            .GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope();
                        using (scope)
                        {
                            var attachedResourceService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<AttachedResourceService>();
                            var providerContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ContentProviderContext>();
                            var resourceId = int.Parse(arguments["id"].ToString());
                            var sourceUrl = attachedResourceService.GetProviderResourceUrl(resourceId, providerContext.User.Id);
                            context.Request.Method = "POST";
                            context.Request.Headers.Add("auth", providerContext.User.Token);
                            return sourceUrl.Url;              
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

The weird thing is; this works, but only when calling from Postman, directly from the address bar in the browser, or from a static HTML page. BUT... it returns a 403 every time I make the resource request from within my own app, from like a view or template.

So when I add an img tag to a static local plain HTML page it works:

`<img src="https://localhost:5001/attached_resource/104" />`

When I put the EXACT same img tag in a .cshtml view or layout, the chrome console (and the asp.net core app terminal) shows returning 403.

Using asp.net core 3.1 with a few server-side rendered Blazor components. So a plain MVC app, not an all-out Blazor app.

I must be missing something very obvious. Any ideas? Thanks for thinking along with me.

Comment: But a break point in line `context.Request.Headers.Add("auth", providerContext.User.Token);` There's chance your token is null

Comment: Thanks for the input but I already went down that route. Even hardcoded the token on every call. Still the same issue.

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with the token itself. How do protected /attached_resource ? Do you have security policy or role based policy ?

Comment: Figured it out; had to remove the header value for Referer (context.Request.Headers.Remove("Referer")). Thanks for your time.